# giving arrayoutofbound exception.......related to cursor in android

Tags: android, cursor

```
l = new ArrayList<String>();
        db =openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        String sql1 = "create table if not exists words(word text primary key, meaning text not null )";
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        String sql = "select word from words";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        int i=0;
        if (c.isBeforeFirst())
    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
        l.add(c.getString(i));
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: 07-03 06:40:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(965): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dictionary/com.example.dictionary.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: Have you read the link i just gave?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the condition to `if(c.moveToFirst())` and set the while condition to be at the end, because otherwise you move to the next statement before you could get something from the cursor. Your code should looks like this:

```
l = new ArrayList<String>();
db =openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
String sql1 = "create table if not exists words(word text primary key, meaning text not null )";
db.execSQL(sql1);
String sql = "select word from words";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
int i=0;
if(c.moveToFirst())
    do
    {
        l.add(c.getString(i));
        i++;
    } while(c.moveToNext())
}
```